# how to remove jaggedness from border of skewed div

Tags: css

I want to skew bordered div, but the border looks jagged or pixelated, also I tried to use `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` but it still pixelated.

Below is my code:

```css
div{
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  transform: skew(-10deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  This Div Is Awesome
</div>
```

Comment: looks fine on my machine, can you give some more information. f.e. What browser are you using?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Looks fine on mine too, chrome on a mac.